# How do I write a formula to enter data in one cell that will update other cells identically in the same sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need a formula that will allow me to enter data in one cell and have that amount be replicated in other cells in the same sheet without changing the other formulas.

Comment: Would you please give us some examples. What do you mean by " without changing the other formulas" ? It obviously can't be as simple as enter data in A1 then cell  B1 contains "= A1". What is in B1 that can't be changed yet needs to replicate A1 ?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not formula savvy, but what they're looking for is a cell that can have a value entered in to it (i.e. the cost of one man day) and have that number be replicated in all of the other areas that value appears on the spread sheet

Answer (score 0):

to duplicate the whole column you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A)
```

or shorter:

```
={A1:A}
```

[image]